# Deploy error on Google cloud in Springboot - deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

Actually I m quite new in Google cloud. So I am getting this error which is given below at the time of deploy project from local to GCP.

I have created springboot project and successfully added appengine-maven-plugin and projectId as well. but it getting error.

> Plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectId>*******</projectId>
                <version>1</version>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

> app.yaml

```
runtime: java
env: flex

 handlers:
 - url: /.*
script: this field is required, but ignored
```

> Error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project user-management-service: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: How do you deploy your your App Engine? WHich command? Where is stored the app.yaml file? Which Java version do you use?

Comment: I am using java8 and app.yaml file is stored on src/appengine/app.yaml location and I am using mvn appengine:deploy command to deploy from STS.

Comment: Now I am using another way to deploy that is from cloud shell.

Actually I created a simple project in spring boot and deploy after set appengine-maven-plugin, version and app.yaml like same process

But now it give me same error with this message:

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: In place deployments over an existing Flexible Environment version are not supported. Please use a different version name, or delete the existing version first.

Comment: with this commond ./mvnw -DskipTests spring-boot:run, I am able to run locally In cloud shell and STS environment both.

Comment: Did you try with a standard environment instead of flex env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was related to the version. That's why it was getting error like INVALID_ARGUMENT

After mention GCLOUD_CONFIG argument of version in pom.xml, it's working

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</version>
        <projectId>demo-project</projectId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```